# Android: How to remove line between Toolbar and Statusbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am interested in having a uniform coloured toolbar and status bar. If I provide `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` as the same colour this should be possible. I am getting the desired result using ActionBar but not with Toolbar. I will also be creating a navigation view so i need the status bar as transparent.

[image: Using Toolbar]
[image: Using ActionBar]

Code : Styles-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Code : Styles

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

Steps to reproduce :

1. Create a new project in android studio with `Navigation Drawer Activity`
2. Set `primary` and `primaryDark` as same colours
3. Run on device or emulator

Comment: Please show screen with the line

Comment: The upper one has the line separating toolbar and status bar. Both colour primary and primary dark have same values.

Comment: I've the same problem. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with was to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="True"` from Coordinator Layout

**edit : Another solution is to wrap coordinator layout in another coordinator layout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Before 
[image]

After 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This shadow you are seeing is window content overlay, you could remove it:

Please add this line to your theme specification:

`<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

Comment: Didn't work. The shadow is still there

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        </style>

Comment: So i removed the toolbar and the shadow was gone. So i think that the shadow is cast both on top and bottom by the toolbar. Setting the elevation of toolbar in both xml and java doesnt help.

Comment: @CuriousCat did you ever figure this out?